# Wake lock not working properly in Custom System Service in Android

Tags: android, android-source

I have created my custom System service and that service is started by SystemServer.
I want to aquire wakelock but it is not working properly. I am doing various tasks in this service like starting application, handling key events etc.. But it only unlocks the screens @ Menu Button event.  Is there something related to keyevents and If I want to unlock screen while starting any app just like phone app, then is there any need to set particular Intent ?

here is my code snippet :

```
public TestService(Context context){    
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,TAG);    
    mWorker = new WorkerThread();
    mWorker.start();
   }    
      WorkerThread extends Thread{   

      public void run(){    
     if(condition){
     // It is not working.
     mWakeLock.aquire();    
  }        
 }        
}
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Yuvi

Comment: Did you specify wake lock permission in manifest file: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: I don't think that there is any mean to provide permission for System Services.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your code is right.

But I think that the problem in your case that you try to acquire very strong wakelock. That's why, I guess, your code is not working. Try to use more weaker wakelock type, for instance, PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK.

If there are any errors in a logcat, can you put it here?

Comment: NO error, And it doesn't matter which WakeLock we aquire. Its behaving so weridly that in the second call of that condtion it works not in first.

Comment: Maybe your service is started before PowerManagerService?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the documentation PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK is the only lock where the CPU continues to run, all others could be put to sleep by the user.

> If you hold a partial wakelock, the CPU will continue to run, irrespective of any timers >and even after the user presses the power button. In all other wakelocks, the CPU will run, >but the user can still put the device to sleep using the power button.
>
> > http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Just look at the table on the site posted above...

also you have to declare a permission in your manifest as said in documentation

> Any application using a WakeLock must request the android.permission.WAKE_LOCK permission >in an  element of the application's manifest.
>
> > http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

but why would you acquire a FULL_WAKE_LOCK on a service where no user interaction is needed?